# How to parse JSON values inside nested array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

I have an array like below provided. Now I want to get all values of "name" key with looping. How to get that?

I tried. But I can't get the correct result

```
dangle=  [[{name:"jack",age:"20"}],
         [{name:"ram",age:"25"}], 
         [{name:"vishy",age:"45"}]]
```

I expect "jack", "ram", "vishy". But it shows first index values like "jack", "20". Below Attached my tried code. Give me a suggestion to get the correct output. Thank you

This is my code

```
for(i=0;i<dangle.length;i++)
{
   alert(dangle[i]);
}
```

Comment: I tried but i forget to post that.I just updated.revote for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to iterate/loop through an array. One common way it using a `for` loop. There can be many variations of a for loop:

- standard `for` loop (loops through numbers where `i` is each number):

  ```
  for(let i = 0; i < dangle.length; i++) { // loop through the dangle array
    let arr = dangle[i]; // get each inner array from index `i`
    for(let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) { // loop through the inner array
      console.log(arr[j].name); // print the name of each object
    }
  }
  ```

```js
let dangle =  [[{name:"jack",age:"20"}], [{name:"ram",age:"25"}],[{name:"vishy",age:"45"}]];
        
for (let i = 0; i < dangle.length; i++) {
  let arr = dangle[i];
  for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    console.log(arr[j].name);
  }
}
```

- `for of` loop (loops through the array elements, where `arr` is the element):

  ```
  for(let arr of dangle) { // get each inner array in dangle (current inner array is referenced as arr)
    for(let obj of arr) { // loop through the contents in the current inner array, where obj is the contents
      console.log(obj.name); // print the name of the contents
    }
  }
  ```

```js
let dangle =  [[{name:"jack",age:"20"}],[{name:"ram",age:"25"}],[{name:"vishy",age:"45"}]];
         
for(let arr of dangle) {
  for(let obj of arr) {
    console.log(obj.name);
  }
}
```

- `.forEach` high-order function (loops through array elements, where `arr` is the element in each array)

  ```
  dangle.forEach(arr => arr.forEach(obj => {
    console.log(obj.name);
  }));
  ```

```js
let dangle =  [[{name:"jack",age:"20"}],[{name:"ram",age:"25"}], [{name:"vishy",age:"45"}]];         

dangle.forEach(arr => arr.forEach(obj => { // loop through the outer array to access each inner array, loop through each inner array
  console.log(obj.name); // print the objects name retrieved from the inner array
}));
```

**Notice**: In the above examples, I've used 2 loops. The reason for this is because you have a 2-dimensional array (an array within another array). This means the outer for loop is used to access each inner array. The inner for loop then loops through the elements (objects in your case) in each inner array. As you only have one object in each inner array, the inner for loop can be removed and you can access the `0th` index of each inner array. However, for the purposes of extendability and maintainability, I've used an inner for loop such that if you do have more than one object this will still work

Thus, you can use one of these for loop to populate an empty array with your names:

```
let names = [];
for(let arr of dangle) {
  for(let obj of arr) {
    names.push(obj.name); // add the name to the names array
  }
}

console.log(names);
```

```js
let dangle=  [[{name:"jack",age:"20"}], [{name:"ram",age:"25"}], [{name:"vishy",age:"45"}]]

let names = [];
for(let arr of dangle) {
  for(let obj of arr) {
    names.push(obj.name); // add the name to the names array
  }
}

console.log(names);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.map()` and `.concat()` to get an array of names only:

```js
const data = [
  [{name:"jack",age:"20"}],
  [{name:"ram",age:"25"}], 
  [{name:"vishy",age:"45"}]
];

const result = [].concat(...data).map(({ name }) => name);

console.log(result);
```